# destructuring assignment default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

I am learning javascript and I got kind of stuck with ES6 syntax while trying to give a default value to a variable when destructuring.
Basically, I am trying to assign a variable giving the value of an object's property to it and if the value is false/null/undefined, I want it to be an  empty object.
For example,

```
let foo = { 
            prop1: 'hello!',
            prop2: null 
           }

const prop1 = foo.prop1 || {}
const prop2 = foo.prop2 || {}

console.log(prop1) //  hello!
console.log(prop2) //  {}
```

This is what I want and  is ES6 sugar syntax I thought as equivalent to above(it doesn't work tho..)

```
let foo = { 
            prop1: 'hello!',
            prop2: null 
           }

const { prop1 = {} } = foo
const { prop2 = {} } = foo

console.log(prop1) // hello!
console.log(prop2) // null
```

but somehow, sometimes it seems working in React, but the other times it doesn't.. is it compatibility problem? so confusing!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You probably confused by the difference between null and undefined, For example:

```
const { dogName = 'snickers' } = { dogName: undefined }
console.log(dogName) // what will it be? 'snickers'!

const { dogName = 'snickers' } = { dogName: null }
console.log(dogName) // what will it be? null!

const { dogName = 'snickers' } = { dogName: false }
console.log(dogName) // what will it be? false!

const { dogName = 'snickers' } = { dogName: 0 }
console.log(dogName) // what will it be? 0!

const { dogName = 'snickers' } = { }
console.log(dogName) // what will it be? 'snickers'!
```

Taken from: http://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values/

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not compatibility problem.

Default value will works if there's no value, meaning that it will work if it is `undefined`. From your example, you're assigning `null` to `prop2`, and `null` is a defined value.

So it will work if your `prop2` is not defined or assigned with `undefined`

```
let foo = { 
        prop1: 'hello!',
        prop2: undefined 
       }

const { prop1 = {} } = foo
const { prop2 = {} } = foo

console.log(prop1) // hello!
console.log(prop2) // {}
```

Comment: ahhhh I finally got the actual difference between null and undefined thanks alot!

Comment: FWIW, `undefined` is a value too, but since it's also the value that you get when a property doesn't exist or an argument is not passed it was decided to have the default applied when `undefined` is the value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I might have some problems to explain that in my answer above. Thank you Felix.

Comment: What if foo is undefined?

Comment: It will return `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`