# ES2016 default parameter as empty array causes "no-empty-pattern" warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am in the process of building a React app which I have used Create React App as the build-environment. Within one of my (class-based) components I have the following line within the `componentDidUpdate()` method:

`const toast = ([] = this.props.toast.toast);`

If my understanding is correct, this is ES2016 syntax for setting default values if a variable is undefined. (Please let me know if this is not correct, although it's not the primary point of this question).

When my React app renders, I get the following warning in the console: `Unexpected empty array pattern  no-empty-pattern`.

I understand that ESLint "moaning" about the fact it's an empty array. But **as I want an empty array in that situation, why does this cause a warning?**

Can I simply tell ESLint to ignore it (using `// eslint-disable-line no-empty-pattern`)?

Comment: Nope, you're understanding is way off. It's possible to use the `=` sign to do default value with parameters, `function(param = []) {}`, but for a typical assignment, you'd want `const toast = this.props.toast.toast || [];`, which is just a logical OR short-circuit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: Another one about function parameters: [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148901/1218980) which points to another good duplicate.

Comment: [Default values when destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49233891/1218980) which also has a duplicate leading to a simple `||` when the value is not specifically `undefined`.

Comment: Also, about [`no-empty-pattern`, looking at the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-pattern) for the rule explains quite well what's happening.

Comment: Thanks all for the links, turns out it was Prettier adjusting my errant syntax to produce the line I included in the question. This was compounded by my lack of experience with ES2016 and making some frankly terrible assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not doing what you think it's doing at all. It's not setting anything to an empty array, nor is it a syntax for default variables. What it's doing is abusing array destructuring syntax without benefit. Try it yourself: if you execute this code, the value of `toast` will be undefined:

```
const toast = ([] = undefined);
```

There is no ES6 syntax for default variables, as far as I know, other than default *function parameters*, which is quite different from what you're using. If you want default variable values, just use the tried-and-true method of short-circuiting:

```
const toast = this.props.toast.toast || [];
```

To elaborate, proper array destructuring works something like this (assuming this.props.toast.toast is an array):

```
const [first, second, third] = this.props.toast.toast;
first === this.props.toast.toast[0]; // true
second === this.props.toast.toast[1]; // true
third === this.props.toast.toast[2]; // true
```

Comment: Beware, without `const` (or `let`) before to the destructuring syntax, it creates global variables.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yep, well-spotted! That's what I get for editing in examples too quickly :) I've fixed it. Thanks!