# Paywall check code in React / Graphql. Need a little bit of clarification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm working on another developers code that paywalls certain articles. I'm looking at this chunk here

```js
  const { paywall = false, iconGroup } = isPaywall({
    group: article.frontmatter.group,
    subjects: article.frontmatter.subjects
  });
```

and I'm a bit confused as to the paywall = false section. Is it always setting paywall to false? I've never seen items declared like that in any other code I've done or come across. Does it make the default value false?

Comment: Yes, it's just a default value assigned to paywall if it's undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233952/6124657

Comment: Right on, thanks folks!