# JS. Object destructuring with default value not working

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

Object:

```
    fruits {
      citrus {
        lime {
          id
        }
      }
      berries {
        ...
      }
    }
```

Destructuring fruits to reach lime:

```
const { citrus: { lime } = {} } = fruits;
```

My understanding is that **if citrus is null**, the destructuring will work and the value of lime will be an empty object {}. However this is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: First block has `lime` but the second one has `limes`.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, fixed question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working here?

Comment: Default only works for `undefined` not null values: [destructuring assignment default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233891) (I've already closed with another reason. You can close it as a duplicate of this)

Comment: I guess @adiga is correct. Surprising it works for '', undefined (returns undefined) but not for `null`

Comment: Okay, well, that solves my issue I guess. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @ABGR default won't work for empty string either. It's just that it will try to access `lime` property from an empty string: `"".lime` and it's not an error, it will return `undefined`

Comment: @adiga okay cool.

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this:

```js
const { citrus = {} } = fruits;
```

or

```js
const { citrus: { lime = {} } } = fruits;
```

but not how you showed it, it doesn't work like this

Comment: If `citrus` is null, this won't work either

Comment: I am pretty sure it won't work like this `const { citrus: { lime } = {} } = fruits;` what variable will be assign to empty object?

Comment: The second block in your asnwer is not assigning default value when `citrus` is `undefined`.

Comment: The second part is just for example, to show in perspecitve

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure it doesn't work like this: `const { citrus: { lime } = {} } = fruits;`*" It does. You can easily test it. It will assign empty object literal when `citrus` is undefined.

Comment: I did before answering doesn’t work for me, it is pointless default

Comment: It is not pointless. `const { citrus: { lime } = {} } = {}` will not throw an error. But `const { citrus: { lime={} } } = {}` will