# How to destructor the response from the useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a useQuery hook which calls an api and returns the response like :

```
return {
  title : response?.data?.[0]?.title,
  desc: response?.data?.[0]?.desc,
}
```

I have the useQuery like this :

```
const {data: content} = useQuery('entitle', apiCall)
```

Here, I am trying to destructor this data like :

```
const {data: {title : [], desc: []}}  = useQuery('entitle', apiCall)
```

Now, it gives can not read property title of undefined while using it . How can I fix this ?

Comment: What are those `[]` supposed to be doing? I think you just want `const { data: { title, desc } } = ...`

Comment: they are default values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [destructuring assignment default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233952/283366). TL;DR default values are assigned via `=`... `const { data: { title = [], desc = [] } } = ...`

Comment: @Phil No this does not work , it still give me undefined

Comment: What is `undefined`? Works fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/t8k0s257/

Comment: Here, before api call only this gets called that why it is coming as undefined

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
const {
  data
} = useQuery('entitle', apiCall)

console.log(data)
```

And pls check if `data` has the structure you expect. If the request is done alright, then I guess you must expect the log to look like this.

```
{
  title: "something",
  desc: "something-else"
}
```

If the structure of the object is not like that or you get `undefined`. Then you got a problem either with the request or the hook call, somehow the query is not returning what you desire.

If the structure is the one you expect it to be, then write what good `Phil` wrote earlier in your post's comment.

```
const {
  data: {
    title = [],
    desc = []
  }
} = useQuery('entitle', apiCall)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont complicate the things

```js
const {data} = useQuery('entitle', apiCall)
const {title=[], desc=[]} = data
```