# Destructuring assignment for dict with default values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I saw a [JS syntax](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/react/simple#creating-a-charting-component) as following:

```js
export const ChartComponent = props => {
    const {
        data,
        colors: {
            backgroundColor = 'white',
            lineColor = '#2962FF',
            textColor = 'black',
            areaTopColor = '#2962FF',
            areaBottomColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
        } = {},  // what is that curly brace?
    } = props;
    ...
}
```

I've read the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), but I still don't know what the curly braces do?

It seems a default value for `colors`, but I don't know why.

As far as I know:

1. the syntax only assigns destructuring values to `data` / `backgroundColor` / `lineColor` / `textColor` / `areaTopColor` / `areaBottomColor`, not including `colors`.
2. The destructuring variables (`backgroundColor` / `lineColor` / `textColor` / `areaTopColor` / `areaBottomColor`) already have their own default values.

Is the curly braces for `color` necessary? What does it do?

Comment: default if undefined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233891/destructuring-assignment-default-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  `= {}` is there to cover for one edge case:

If you DO have a `props` value that is an object, but it DOES NOT have a property named `colors` or the property is there but IS NOT a destructurable object.

For example:

```
props = { data: 0}

const {
    data,
    colors: {
        backgroundColor = 'white',
        lineColor = '#2962FF',
        textColor = 'black',
        areaTopColor = '#2962FF',
        areaBottomColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
    },  // no default value provided
} = props;
```

You would have:

> TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured

In this context, `{}` is just an empty object, used as a default value (you could have used any other object value). It will be used in case no destructurable object can match a property with name `colors`.

Comment: The error i get seems to differ from what you've added `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`, thats what i get when no `{}` exists

Answer (score 2):

the answer given by [@Rodrigo Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938526/rodrigo-rodrigues) explains the reason. I will give an example

Lets say the `props` doesn't have `colors`. Then in the destructuring `colors` will be `undefined` and it looks like trying to destructure the properties `backgroundColor` etc. from an undefined. Even though you have the default values for `backgroundColor` it can't destructure the undefined.

```js
const props = {
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}

const {
  data,
  colors: {
    backgroundColor = 'white',
    lineColor = '#2962FF',
    textColor = 'black',
    areaTopColor = '#2962FF',
    areaBottomColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
  },
} = props

console.log(backgroundColor)
```

Now with the `{}` it handles this case and assigns a default `{}` when `colors` in not found in props. After that it tries to destructure that empty object which is possible. Since then `backgroundColor` is not present in the `{}` it will be assigned with the default value for `backgroundColor` which is white

```js
const props = {
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}

const {
  data,
  colors: {
    backgroundColor = 'white',
    lineColor = '#2962FF',
    textColor = 'black',
    areaTopColor = '#2962FF',
    areaBottomColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
  } = {},
} = props

console.log(backgroundColor)
```